# Code optimization - removing nested left joins

Tags: mysql, sql

To make this query more efficient, I was hoping that it would be possible to eliminate the nested `LEFT JOIN`. I thought about whether it would be possible to replace `COUNT(ActiveUsers)` with `COUNT(DISTINCT IF(SUM(grand_total)>0,id,NULL))` so that I could remove the `LEFT JOIN`, however this doesn't seem to get the correct results.  Here's the original code that I'm using:

```
SELECT
COUNT(DISTINCT users.id) AS NumCustomer,
COUNT(ActiveUsers) AS NumActiveCustomers,
COUNT(ActiveUsers)/COUNT(DISTINCT username) AS CloseRate
FROM users
LEFT JOIN orders ON orders.userid = users.id
LEFT JOIN (SELECT id AS ActiveUsers FROM users LEFT JOIN orders ON orders.userid = users.id GROUP BY id HAVING SUM(grand_total)>0 ) AS Active ON users.id = Active.ActiveUsers
WHERE users.datecreated LIKE '2013%'
GROUP BY YEAR(users.created), MONTH(users.created)
ORDER BY YEAR(users.created), MONTH(users.created)
```

Is there a way I could make this code more efficient?

Comment: I don't think you need to `LEFT JOIN` on the orders table, because you want the sum of grant_totalto be >0. An INNER JOIN should work

Comment: First post an EXPLAIN output here and your table structure and used storage engine..

Comment: And redefine your SQL code in plain english what you need..

Comment: Hi. Yeah. What I'm producing here is the number of Customers and the number of Customers who have bought something, which I call ActiveCustomers. All users are in the users table and any orders made are in the orders table. So I check if they've ever bought anything by checking grand_total>0.

Answer (score 0):

If grand_total can't be negative:

```
SELECT
    COUNT(DISTINCT users.id) AS NumCustomer,
    COUNT(distinct orders.userid) AS NumActiveCustomers,
    COUNT(distinct orders.userid)/COUNT(DISTINCT users.username) AS CloseRate
FROM users
LEFT JOIN orders ON orders.userid = users.id
WHERE users.datecreated LIKE '2013%' and grand_total>0
GROUP BY YEAR(users.created), MONTH(users.created)
ORDER BY YEAR(users.created), MONTH(users.created)
```

(If it can't be zero either, then you don't need the second where condition.)

Comment: Hmmm... yeah. let me try this one. The COUNT(DISTINCT users.username) would count all users and then COUNT(distinct orders.userid) will count all users that have entries in the orders table.